# Android regular check for internet connection

Tags: android, webview, connectivity

I'm running an android app that displays a webview on specific URL, I want to check if the application server I'm accessing is alive and that I can view HTML, if failed I should terminate the webview, this check should be every 10 seconds (or whatever), what is the best approach for this ?

Comment: I think service can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Timer [(here you have information)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and when timer tick, ping any host :

```
 URL url = new URL("http://microsoft.com");

    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application:"+Z.APP_VERSION);
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30); // mTimeout is in seconds
            urlc.connect();
    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        Main.Log("getResponseCode == 200");
            return new Boolean(true);
    }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If return true : connection is active. Else isn't active.

Comment: What is the purpose of  HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an AsyncTask so your app doesn't freezes.

```
private class checkServer extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            questionRunning = true;

            //check if server is running

            //now wait 10.000ms (10sec) 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(params[0]);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Update your layout here
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //Do it again!
            new checkServer().execute(10000);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }
    }
```

How to call your AsynTask:

```
new checkServer().execute(10000);
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but thought it is not the intended use of async task, it is about progress and UI, and initializing a new asynctask every some seconds is not efficient enough, or what do you think ?

Comment: You have to use a new threat, otherwise your main threat freezes for a few (mili)seconds. You don't want this to happen! You can use an AsyncTask and a Timer for this problem. When you create a Timer you also start a new threat, an Asynctask is optimized for Android so I think it's a good solution.

Comment: Aha I got it, I will try that

Answer (score 1):

***Using-BroadCastReceiver-Way-It's Efficient-to-implement&realistic***

`As you're saying that you need to check the specific server for alive() or not?. Then it depends upon your choice. But always try to be general.`

**To receive for Internet Connectivity dropped / up, listen for 
'ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION' action.**

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver, filter);
```

**Whenever there is a change in connectivity i.e it could be either data connection is connected or disconnected, you will receive this event as broadcast, so in onreceive of the broadcast receiver, please check for internetconnect connection and decide whether internet is up or down.**

```
     BroadcastReceiver mNetworkStateIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
     {  
      @Override  
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
       {  
         if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
         {  

             NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(  
                     ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);  
             String typeName = info.getTypeName();  
             String subtypeName = info.getSubtypeName();  
              System.out.println("Network is up ******** "+typeName+":::"+subtypeName);  

             if( checkInternetConnection()== true )  
             {  
                    "Decide your code logic here...."  
              }  
          }  
        }
      }

private boolean checkInternetConnection() 
{  
 ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
 // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET  
 if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null  && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()  &&conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
  {  
   return true;  
  } 
 else
  {  
     return false;  
  }    
}
```

Hope it may helps you somewhere!!

Comment: I know about the conenction manager and already using it to check general internet connection, but in my case I want to check for our server specifically, thank you